# Mechanize can't find form by action

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have the following code

```
mechanize = Mechanize.new do |agent| 
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'
end
page = mechanize.get("https://sports.bwin.com/en/sports#leagueIds=6004&sportId=7")
puts page.body
form = page.form_with(:action => "/en/sports/indexmultileague")
pp form
```

I can see from the output of puts page.body that a form with the action I'm looking for exists in the html but pp form just prints nil

Comment: Are you sure the form isn't created by JavaScript?

Comment: Would that mean mechanize can't get it? My understanding was that it parses the final output HTML in the same way a browser might?

Comment: @db579 Can you share the url of the page from which you are trying to get the form? Better edit the answer and add it there, assuming its not a password protected page which will require your username/password

Comment: @db579 Mechanize doens't handle JS. For that you'd need Watir, PhantonJS, or other JS-capable webdriver.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman I've edited the question. I'm basically just trying to manipulate the checkboxes on the page.

Comment: The form isn't there but you can probably figure out how to post it with `Mechanize#post`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I view the page source, I am not able to see such a form with that action.

However, using Chrome inspector tool(which shows the dynamic in-memory page source), I am able to see that form.

This means the form is being generated dynamically via a script and `Mechanize` does not support scripts.

You will need to use a web driver that supports scripts.

For example, if you are using Selenium, you can look at the forms section [here](https://gist.github.com/kenrett/7553278).

You can dive into [Selenium's documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/) to get around what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: I see. I appreciate it is probably beyond the scope of this question but would you be able to post an example?